# Making an Ajax call for Vue multiselect options in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to convert autocomplete functionality from Jquery with an input into a Vue multiselect.

I'm most of the way there but I still have some errors or incompletions somewhere here. I have a basic div with the multislect which shows on the page. Then I have the vue instance which is where I'm making a call to my Route (the route is hit successfully and it triggers the function in my controller below)

My biggest issue, I believe, is I have no idea how to make the multiselect search act as my query in the ajax call so that I can populate my `options` in the vue instance.

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

HTML:

```
 <div id="app">
      <multiselect v-model="value" open-direction="bottom" :options="options" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :taggable="true" :clear-on-select="false" :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Choose Option(s)" label="name" track-by="name">
          <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }"><span class="multiselect__single" v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen">{{ values.length }} options selected</span></template>
      </multiselect>
  </div>
```

Vue:

```
let app = new Vue({
        components: {
            Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
        },
        data () {
            return {
                selected: 'A',
                options: []
            }
        },
        methods:{
            pullEmployees(){

               $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('campaigns.search') }}",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{query:query, _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
                    success: results => this.options = results
                });
            }
        }
    }).$mount('#app');
```

Controller:

```
public function searchTags(Request $request)
{

    if($request->get('query'))
    {
      $query = $request->get('query');
      $data = CampaignTags::where('TAG_DATA', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();

      return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to my attention is that you are using `success: results => this.options = results` in your success function for the ajax request. One common mistake is that `this` in this particular context doesn't refer to the vue instance but the ajax request.

So what could get you a step further is to create an explicit reference to the vue instance upfront:

```
pullEmployees() { 
   var vue = this; 
   $.ajax({
      url:"{{ route('campaigns.search') }}",
      method:"POST",
      data:{query:query, _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
      success: results => vue.options = results
    });
  }
```

This should at least set the your vue instance `options` to the `results` provided by the ajax request.

Maybe you can proceed further with this information.

Comment: Thanks I will try this! Another thing is I think I need a keyup for the search